# Why is C++ WMI Not Fetching Data? Error: 0xC0000005

Tags: c++, powershell, permissions, wmi

I'm quite new to WMI, I'm following this guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer).

So I pasted that code in the guide and ran it without any issues using the provided query. But when I changed the query to `SELECT State FROM Win32_Service` I get no data, just the error code 0xC0000005, which I believe is a permissions error?

That same query above works just fine in the PowerShell using the following command:

`Get-WmiObject -Query "select State from Win32_Service"`

What I've tried

- winrm quickconfig

So what gives? Why am I having trouble querying the WMI from my C++ code?

EDIT: I found the line that's causing the crash. I'm not sure why it's crashing though.

```
wcout << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed this line of code

```
hr = pclsObj->Get(L"State", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
```

Change the first argument to the property whose value you'd like to retrieve.